# How to send yes when executing a custom command in laravel?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I am making a multitenant application using spatie/multi-tenancy. And I need to migrate the database when the new tenant is created. However, as the application is in production, it prompts before migration. I am executing this command.

```
Artisan::call("tenants:artisan 'migrate --seed' --tenant={$tenant->id}");
```

This command works perfectly when in the local environment but not when setting up the application in production. I am not able to pass --force as it shows this option does not exist. I want to know how to go about this. I have tried

```
        echo "y" | Artisan::call("tenants:artisan 'migrate --seed' --tenant={$tenant->id}");
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions? Maybe adding some option in the command itself which will automatically send 'yes' when prompted.

Comment: Using the `--force` parameter will not prompt you

Comment: @apokryfos --force does not work as this is a custom command by the package.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/blob/main/src/Commands/TenantsArtisanCommand.php) is where that command is coming from. This just forwards commands to artisan after picking the tenant. You are already passing `--seed` to it as a parameter I would expect that passing `--force` as well (within the single quotes as before) should work

Comment: This works! I was adding the --force option afterwards, which gave the error that the --force option doesn't exist. But adding it next to seed within the single quote worked. Thank you!