# How to execute commands that affect the database in Laravel production?

Tags: laravel

I have a command that I use for the creation of databases in a SaaS platform, migration and seeders, the issue is that if it is in local it works perfect but if I change it to production it gets stuck and does not work.

How could I fix it so that at least also works in production to create accounts without having to be changing the .env file to local?

Spatie/multitenancy commands:

```
php artisan tenants:artisan migrate --tenant=11 --force
php artisan tenant:executeseeder 11 --force
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Certain commands, like `php artisan migrate`, `php artisan db:seed`, etc. when run with `APP_ENV=production` set in your `.env` will display this interactive message when run:

```
php artisan migrate

**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
```

If you're running this via a process that doesn't allow interaction, this will "get stuck", as it is waiting for your confirmation.

To get around this, simply run the commands with `--force`:

```
php artisan migrate --force

Nothing to migrate.
```

Comment: I have placed it but it does not work, it tells me that it does not know the --force command.

Comment: Take a look at this question and the comments; might be the same issue you're having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753632/how-to-send-yes-when-executing-a-custom-command-in-laravel

Comment: Or, this issue on their GitHub page: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/issues/120. It looks like people use a wrapper command that internally calls `Artisan::call('tenants:artisan', ['artisanCommand' => 'migrate --tenant=11 --force'])` (or similar). This is... janky to say the least 